# LWJGL won't read keyboard input

Tags: java, linux, input, lwjgl

I'm trying to use LWJGL to get whether a key is pressed.  If the escape key is pressed, then the application quits.  However, I can't get it to read any keyboard input, although `Display.isCloseRequested()` works fine.

I'm on RHEL using LWJGL 2.6 and Java 1.6.

```
for(;;) {
    // check if we want to quit

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
        System.exit(0);  // can't get this to happen!
    }
    if(Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

/* timer code omitted */

    render();
    Display.update();
}
```

**Edit:** The exact same code works perfectly fine on my Windows box, with the same versions of lwjgl and JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check if the Keyboard is Created with the `isCreated` function?

Other then that I'm not all that good in programming so I can't provide you with any other input.

try this

```
Keyboard.isCreated()
```

Answer (score 0):

I may or may not be helpful/reviving a dead topic here, but for any rogue Googlers I give you this:

[It's my Input class from my Zdeva Engine](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IT6Q0EjKWIuQ9YX3imtVOGZ-NmFAflf2dSH8BYaibCA/edit?pli=1)

Here you go, without having to download the entire 'engine'..

```
package LWJGL;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;

public class Input 
{
    public static boolean[] mouseButtons = {false, false, false};
    public static int[] mousePos = new int[Mouse.getButtonCount()];
    public static int[] keysBound = {Keyboard.KEY_A, Keyboard.KEY_B};

    /**
     * Initializes the input system. Loads keyconfig.
     * 
     */
    public static void init()
    {
        System.out.println("Initializing input system...");
        //Eventually will check for OS, and adjust keys accordingly.
        System.out.println("Input system initialized!");
    }

    /**
     * Updates all mouse info, keys bound, and performs actions.
     */
    public static void tick()
    {
        mouseButtons[0] = Mouse.isButtonDown(0);
        mouseButtons[1] = Mouse.isButtonDown(1);

        mousePos[0] = Mouse.getX();
        mousePos[1] = Mouse.getY();

        while(Keyboard.next())
        {
            if(Keyboard.getEventKeyState())
            {
                doAction(Keyboard.getEventKey(), false);
            }
        }

        for(int key : keysBound)
        {
            if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(key))
            {
                doAction(key, true);
            }
        }

        while(Mouse.next())
        {
            doAction(-1, false);
        }
        doAction(0, true);  
    }

    /**
     * Does the associated action for each key. Called automatically from tick.
     * @param key The key to check & perform associated action
     */
    public static void doAction(int key, boolean ifRepeat)
    {
        if(mouseButtons[0])
        {

        }
        if(mouseButtons[1])
        {

        }
        if(key == keysBound[0] & ifRepeat)
        {
            System.out.println("a");
        }
        if(key == keysBound[1] & !ifRepeat)
        {
            System.out.println("b");            
        }
    }
}
```